# filling of combo in datagrid view

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i have a grid view.in grid view i have combox ,i am trying fill that combobox

my code like this:

```
Dim sqlcombo As String
sqlcombo = "Select F_Cat_name from T_Category"

da = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlcombo, conn)
ds = New DataSet
da.Fill(ds)
dt = ds.Tables(0)
Dim dgvcc As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
With dgvcc
    .DataSource = ds
    .ValueMember = "F_Cat_name"
    .DisplayMember = "F_Cat_name"
End With
DG.Item(2, 0) = dgvcc
```

while running i am getting error like this:
**Field called F_Cat_name does not exist.**

Comment: Why do you assign the ds instead of the dt?

Comment: i want to assign dt?